# Can you fix this Java Regex to match currency such as -10 USD, 12.35 AUD ... (Java)?

Tags: java, regex

I have a need to validate the Currency String as followings:

```
 1. The Currency Unit must be in Uppercase and must contain 3 characters from A to Z
 2. The number can contain negative (-) or positive (+) sign.
 3. The number can contain the decimal fraction, but if the number contain 
the decimal fraction then the fraction must be 2 Decimal only.
 4. There is no space in the number part
```

So see this example:

```
10 USD ------> match
+10 USD ------> match
-10 USD ------> match
10.23 AUD ------> match
-12.11 FRC ------> match
- 11.11 USD ------> NOT match because there is space between negative sign and the number
10  AUD ------> NOT match because there is 2 spaces between the number and currency unit
135.1 AUD ------> NOT match because there is only 1 Decimal in the fraction
126.33 YE ------> NOT match because the currency unit must contain 3 Uppercase characters
```

So here is what I tried but failed

```
if(text != null && text.matches("^[+-]\\d+[\\.\\d{2}] [A-Z]{3}$")){     
  return true;
}
```

The `"^\\d+ [A-Z]{3}$"` only match number without any sign and decimal part.

So Can you fix this Java Regex to match currency that meets the above requirements?

Some other questions in the internet do not match my requirements.

Comment: I think you should use something like (\\.\\d{2})? for the decimal part and also add a ? to the sign part, so that it can be present or not

Comment: tried like u said but it doesn't work

Comment: Just tried it and it works with all the cases you show. "^[+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d{2})? [A-Z]{3}$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you don't know about `?` quantifier which means that element which this quantifier describes can appear zero times or once, making it optional.

So to say that string can contain optional `-` or `+` at start just add `[-+]?`.
To say that it can contain optional decimal part in form `.XX` where `X` would be digit just add `(\\.\\d{2})?`

So try with `"^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d{2})? [A-Z]{3}$"`

---

BTW If you are using `yourString.matches(regex)` then you don't have to add `^` or `$` to regex. This method will match only if entire string will match regex so these metacharacters are not necessary.

BTW2 Normally you should escape `-` in character class `[...]` because it represents range of characters like `[A-Z]` but in this case `-` can't be used this way because it is at start of character class so there is no "first" range character, so you don't have to escape `-` here. Same goes if `-` is last character in `[..-]`. Here it also can't represent range so it is simple literal.

Comment: You're forgetting about the possible first + sign

Answer (score 1):

you could start your regex with

```
^(\\+|\\-)?
```

Which means that it will accept either one `+` sign, one `-` sign or nothing at all before the digit. But that's only one of your problems.

**Now the decimal point:**

*"3. The number can contain the decimal fraction, but if the number contain 
the decimal fraction then the fraction must be 2 Decimal only."*

so after the digit `\\d+` the next part should be in `( )?` to indicate that it is optional (meaning 1 time or never). So either there are *exactly* one dot and two digits or nothing

```
(\\.\\d{2})?
```

[Here you can find a reference for regex and test them](http://regex101.com/#aqr). Just have a look at what else you could use to identify the 3 Letters for the currency. E.g. the `\s`  could help you to identify a whitespace

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
text.matches("[+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d\\d)? [A-Z]{3}")
```

Note that since you use `.matches()`, the regex is automatically anchored (blame the Java API desingers for that: `.matches()` is woefully misnamed)

Answer (score 1):

This will match all your cases:

```
^[-+]?\d+(\.\d{2})?\s[A-Z]{3}$
```

([Demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wX8kY0))

To use it in Java you have to escape the `\`:

```
text.matches("^[-+]?\\d+(\\.\\d{2})?\\s[A-Z]{3}$")
```

Your regex wasn't far from the goal, but it contains several mistakes.
The most important one is: `[]` denotes a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) while `()` is a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). So when you specify a character group like `[\\.\\d{2}]` it will match on the characters `\`,`.`,`d`,`{`,`2`, and`}`, while you want to match on the pattern `.\d{2}`.
The other answers already taught you the [`?` quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html), so I won't repeat this.

On a sidenote: [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info) is a great source to learn these things!

Explanation of the regex used above:

```
^           #start of the string/line
  [-+]?     #optionally a - or a + (but not both; only one character)
  \d+       #one or more numbers
  (         #start of optional capturing group
    \.\d{2} #the character . followed by exactly two numbers (everything optional)
  )?        #end of optional capturing group
  \s        #a whitespace
  [A-Z]{3}  #three characters in the range from A-Z (no lowercase)
$           #end of the string/line
```

Comment: `\w` is too large here, and regex dialect dependent; for one, in pretty much all regex dialect, it will also match digits

Comment: @fge just realized this myself, fixed it